# Win32 ATL application does not use appropriate localized dialogs for system locale

Tags: winapi, localization, resources, atl

How it all happens:

1. To make my Win32 ATL application multi-lingual, I added a copy of GUI Dialogs for each needed language (not for all Dialogs, but for those I use, does it matter?)
2. I change locale for Windows 7 (or Windows 10, result is the same) to what I want, and wishing to see that my Application will use appropriate Dialog language from resources (e.g., es-ES welcome dialog for Spanish locale set in Windows preferences (Region and Languages..) etc...)
3. BUT, it always uses English Dialogs, I see only English welcome dialog, even when I set different locale (of course I restart computer after this change)

Note: in my code, I get current locale on start just to be sure - and it is correct (e.g., es-ES, de-DE, etc...), but in Application Details window (in Windows Explorer) I see Application Language: English (US) and only this, and all application Dialogs are all only in English.

I already tried both: making my Application Unicode and Multi-Byte... result is still the same - only English resources are used to draw strings for my Dialogs.

Please, help me, telling what I am doing wrong.

Thank you

P.S. something from comments, one more explanation:
I added a copy of Welcome Dialog (2 textboxes and text editor area) for each language (say English(default), Spanish and Deutsch) and HOPE that it is enough. I execute my built application if certain locale (say Spanish), but get ONLY English dialog. Do I do something wrong or not enough? That is my question... Should I explicitely load certain resource or it will be done automatically? etc... Thank you

And I should say that it is a legacy project and I am restricted to use VS 2010

Comment: Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?

Comment: Stick with Unicode. Multibyte is old.  Application has to look at user settings and pick the right language. It's no clear how you are doing that. One way to do it, you can create multiple "resource-only dll files", then use `FindResource` to see language dialog is there, otherwise default to English.

Comment: Actually, I listed each step that was done. I should add that this is legacy project and I am restricted to use VS 2010.

Comment: I added a copy of Welcome Dialog (2 textboxes and text editor area) for each language (say English(default), Spanish and Deutsch) and HOPE that it is enough. I execute my built application if certain locale (say Spanish), but get ONLY English dialog. Do I do something wrong or not enough? That is my question... Should I explicitely load certain resource or it will be done automatically? etc... Thank you

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT, if you got the problem, you could see, that I have a Standard Win32 ATL Application with 1 Dialog (with 2-3 controls) and 2 COPIES of this dialogs for 2 other languages (made in VS 2010 using "Insert copy" option). That's ALL. Next I just build and run it in DIFFERENT (changed) Windows locales, wishing to get needed Dialog language for certain locale. That's all and nothing else is there.